# Using Roadie 3 With Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use the [Roadie 3 gem](https://github.com/Mange/roadie) in a Rails 4 application and I can't figure out how to make it work.

Once I add the gem to my bundle I .

```
class SuggestionMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "hi@app.com"

  def suggestions(user, suggestions)
    @suggestions = suggestions
    @stylesheets = %w[/assets/ink/base.css /assets/suggestion_mailer/suggestions.css]

    mail(to: user.email, subject: subject)
  end
end
```

The stylesheets are added to the email HTML in this loop:

```
<head>      
  <% @stylesheets.each do |href| %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= href -%>" >
  <% end -%>
</head>
```

It all seems to work fine in the development environment using [the MailView gem](https://github.com/Mange/roadie).

However, when I actually send my emails via SMTP or to [Mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/), Roadie doesn't appear to inline the stylesheets before they are sent. I'll receive an unstyled email with `<link/>` tags still intact in the `<head/>` of the email.

At first I thought the issue was being caused by the fact that I'm sending my emails in a background process but the issue persists when I send them directly from the Rails console.

The [Roadie Readme](https://github.com/Mange/roadie) seems more concerned with showing how to use it from outside Rails than within.

How am I supposed to get Roadie 3 to work with Rails 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, there's [a separate gem](https://github.com/Mange/roadie-rails) for using Roadie 3 in Rails. They just don't mention it on the Roadie README yet. Currently it's really early alpha so you might want to wait before trying to use it.

Comment: If you came here with the same issue and you're wondering what I did instead... you should check out the [premailer-rails gem](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails). It's working great for me.

Comment: Actually this is absolutely wrong: You DON'T need a separate GEM for using Roadie 3 in Rails 4. I'm using only Roadie 3 and it works just fine. If you look at premailer... it basically does the exact same thing that Roadie 3 does... so why would you have two gems that do the same thing? I think the problem was with the way you setup your stylesheets.

Comment: @mysticcola So there's a quote on [the Roadie 3 readme](http://goo.gl/VSG4uG) which says "This gem was previously tied to Rails. It is now framework-agnostic and supports any type of HTML documents. If you want to use it with Rails, check out roadie-rails." yet you're telling me that I'm "absolutely" wrong to use a separate gem and down-voting me?

Comment: Absolutely. Pre-mailer and Roadie do the same thing... If you're running Pre-Mailer... why would you run Roadie, too? If you've got an answer for that... I'll retract my comment and upvote you. On my side... I believe I can actually help you find your problem and get ONLY Roadie 3 to work with Rails 4 (since I've done it), if that's what you still want to do.

Comment: @mysticcola I'm not using Pre-mailer though. I never mentioned Pre-mailer once in either my question or answer.

Comment: You mentioned it here (maybe that confused me): "If you came here with the same issue and you're wondering what I did instead... you should check out the premailer-rails gem. It's working great for me. –  David Tuite Dec 3 '13 at 2:03" Anyway I still got it to work without roadie-rails. If you want to chat about it I'd love to figure out why it didn't work for you.

Comment: I was obviously talking about using premailer INSTEAD of roadie, not alongside it. I feel like I'm stuck in an elaborate troll here.

Comment: Yeah... Elaborate trolls always try to help you, right? I'm the only guy that responded to your question. I was just mistaken about the pre-mailer part, but Roadie 3 works with Rails 4 (at least for in-lining styles, which was the whole purpose of your question) WITHOUT the roadie-rails gem. But you don't seem interested in that.

Comment: @mysticcola please post the answer on how you got Roadie 3 to work with Rails 4. If it works I'll give you an upvote ...

Comment: It was a long time ago now. Basically I wrote a simple script to link roadie to rails. It worked fine, but I ended up scrapping roadie altogether because Mailchimp made more sense for what I was trying to do. If I can still find the code I'll post it, otherwise you can just run premailer or see if roadie-rails is out yet. It wasn't anything difficult to get it working though.

Comment: EDIT: Roadie-rails came out two weeks ago. So now you don't even have to do anything. https://github.com/Mange/roadie-rails/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yeah figured it out, I have roadie-rails working well with rails 4. Thanks.